# Why the R script provide by site pubmed is not executing ? Is it possible to make it run?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If possible, I need help to understand why the code below is not working. This code I was found on the page: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3817376/. Would it be possible for any expert member to adapt it to work?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
head(Theoph)

ggplot(data=Theoph, aes(x=Time, y=conc, group=Subject)) + geom_line() + labs(x=“Time (hr)”, y=“Concentration (mg/L)”)

p <- ggplot(data=Theoph, aes(x=Time, y=conc, group=Subject)) + geom_line() + labs(x=“Time (hr)”, y=“Concentration (mg/L)”) + stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom=“line”,aes(x=ntpd, y=conc, group=1), color=“red”, size=1)

print(p) # “p” is a ggplot object

# create a flag for body weight

Theoph$WT <- ifelse(Theoph$Wt<70, “WT < 70kg”, “WT >= 70kg”)
p + facet_grid(.~WT)""t>
```

Comment: The formatting in that article is just completely broken (this is unfortunately a *general* problem in some journal articles, but it’s particularly egregious here). It’s also extremely outdated. I urge you to ignore the article completely and instead learn ‘ggplot2’ (or R) from a proper resource, e.g. *R for data science*.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Would it be possible for you to adapt it to work? Is it very complicated? my code is not executing because this expression: 1) stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom=“line”,aes(x=ntpd, y=conc, group=1), color=“red”, size=1) and 2) Theoph$WT <- ifelse(Theoph$Wt<70, “WT < 70kg”, “WT >= 70kg”). Have you some sugestion for change this expressions? My time is finishing :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to help you run this.

First, you have curly/smart quotes “ in your code, and should just use plain quotes `"`. Sometimes we get this excess formatting when we copy/paste code from other sources like this.

Second, you need to use the supplementary materials to calculate `ntpd`, add to the `Theoph` dataset.

Below is code that seemed to work at my end to reproduce the spaghetti plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

# Reference:
# https://ascpt.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1038/psp.2013.56

head(Theoph)

ggplot(data = Theoph, aes(x = Time, y = conc, group = Subject)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "Time (hr)", y = "Concentration (mg/L)")

##################################################################################
## we need some data manipulation for Figure 1(e) and Figure (f)
## below code is how to calculate approximate ntpd (nominal post time dose)
## "ntpd" is used for summarizing conc data (calculate mean at each time point)
## create body weight category for <70 kg or >=70 kg 
##################################################################################

#--create a cut (time intervals)
Theoph$cut <- cut(Theoph$Time, breaks=c(-0.1,0,1,1.5, 2,3,4,6,8,12,16,20,24)) 

#--make sure each time point has reasonable data
table(Theoph$cut)

#--calcuate approximate ntpd
library(plyr)
tab <- ddply(Theoph, .(cut), summarize, ntpd=round(mean(Time, na.rm=T),2))

#--merge ntpd into Theoph data
Theoph <- merge(Theoph, tab, by=c("cut"), all.x=T)

#--sort the data by Subject and Time, select only nessesary columns
Theoph <- Theoph[order(Theoph$Subject, Theoph$Time),c("Subject","Wt","Dose","Time","conc","ntpd")]

#--create body weight category for <70 kg or >=70 kg for Figure 1(f)
Theoph$WT <- ifelse(Theoph$Wt<70, "WT < 70kg", "WT >= 70kg")

#--end of data manipulation
##################################################################################

p <- ggplot(data = Theoph, aes(x=Time, y=conc, group=Subject)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x="Time (hr)", y="Concentration (mg/L)") + 
  stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "line", aes(x = ntpd, y = conc, group = 1), color = "red", size=1)

print(p)

p + facet_grid(. ~ WT)
```